# What if the players refuse to join the questing pack in the Valkenburg Foundation?

Tags: published-adventures, world-of-darkness, books, werewolf-the-apocalypse

The Werewolf adventure *The Valkenburg Foundation* begins with the players being asked to join the Questing Pack. Their role in the questing pack is pivotal because it is the mechanism used to feed them hooks throughout the rest of the chronicle.

The book provides a section on how to handle players who initially refuse to join up. However, my printing seems to have an error - it leaves off in mid-sentence:

> **Refusal** ... Lucius returns to inform them that he can gain the permission of their sept, if they feel it necessary. He will leave and return in two days bearing a note from Mother Larissa (or their sept elder, if they are not of the Sept of the Green). She bids the pack take

(Source: Valkenburg Foundation pg. 27)

Do other printings or other sources complete this thought?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There has been an errata provided. It was posted on the White Wolf website, but is now accessible through the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20080110120245/http://www.white-wolf.com:80/Download/Assets/Errata/ValkenburgErrata.html):

> **Refusal:**
>   The characters should be urged in every way to take Gretchen's offer. They have
>   been shown the tragedy of the lost cubs and Valkenburg's work to aid them.
>   They have been shown the powerful items due the Questing Pack. If they are
>   waffling on the decision, use one of the following tactics:
>
> - Lucius returns to inform them that he can gain the permission of their sept, if they feel it necessary. He will leave and return in two days bearing a note from Mother Larissa (or their sept elder, if they are not of the Sept of the Green). She bids the pack take the chance for renown and join the sept, and asks that they aid in every way to cure Graveseeker.
> - If they are of the Sept of the Green, then there is another method of drawing them in. The characters can return to NY and get caught up in the events of Story Two, coming face to face with the dangers of an uncontrolled Lunatic. Lucius can show up to drive the point home: join Valkenburg. If this doesn't work, the Sept of the Green may push them to it, after the disastrous consequences in Story Two. This will ensure their Renown, if they doubted it before, by having the sept elders ask the duty of them.